# iphone sdk , apostrophe showing up as question mark

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, nsstring, uitextview

The quotation marks (apostrophe to be more specific) single and double are displaying as question mark on my text view.
The problem come up when I try to copy and paste some thing from a webpage and save it. 
This problem does not happen when I type the sentence. 
How can I replace a apostrophe with a regular single quote?

Answer (score 1):

When you copy from a webpage you are not copying a plain old apostrophe. You are copying a fancy one that looks very similar but is not. Since the text view only displays plain text it cannot understand your fancy apostrophe.

When you copy from a webpage you will have to manually delete and retype the apostrophes.

You have to do a string replace probably with unicode characters. The following may be the characters that you want to replace:

```
Char   Unicode    HTML
“      8220        &#8220;     
‘      8216        &#8216;     
”      8221        &#8221;     
’      8217        &#8217;
```

Comment: you are right, the problem happens with the fancy apostrophe. 
I want to clean the string before i show it up on the textview. So the question now is how and what should I search for and replace in my string? Thanks